# NodeJS Newline delimited strings to array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

How do I make a text file being read as:

```
`{'values': [0,1,0], 'key': 0}
{'values': [1,1,0], 'key': 1}
{'values': [1,1,0], 'key': 1}`
```

via:

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFile("logfile.txt", 'utf8', function(err, data){

  console.log("DATA: ", data);
  return data
   });
  console.log('readFile called');
```

A list of dictionaries newline delimited into an array.

Wanted output:

```
[{'values': [0,1,0], 'key': 0},
    {'values': [1,1,0], 'key': 1},
    {'values': [1,1,0], 'key': 1}]
```

Comment: JSON is a text format, and one of its rules is that keys must be quoted with a specific character (`"`, not `'`). Your "wanted output" is therefore not JSON. It seems what you actually want is an array, not JSON. That said, there is an expectation that askers show some research into their issues (see [ask]).

Comment: I totally couldn't get an idea of how the textfile look like with your question.

Comment: @Gayathri it contains a dictionary-like string per line. I hope to make that as an array of json.

Comment: @HereticMonkey If we go by your terms, I can make it an array of strings and not be able to use its keys because each line hasnt been formatted to json. Thats why I wrote Json because I want to be able to access the values via key in there. But you are correct on not being clear of it being an array.

Comment: No, if we go by my terms, the entire thing would be a string if it was JSON and you wouldn't be able to do anything with it. That's the point. JSON is text. If you want to be able to access the values by index and key, it has to be an array of objects, not JSON.

Comment: I see that makes sense, Im new to nodejs, so my terms might be different. Ill correct the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const str = `{'values': [0,1,0], 'key': 0}
             {'values': [1,1,0], 'key': 1}
             {'values': [1,1,0], 'key': 1}`;
```

Seeing the structure of the string, you can parse it with a regex to extract the objects

```
const match = str.match(/({.*})/gm);
```

Then you have to correct the string to use double quote (JSON uses double quotes only) and parse each string

```
const result = match.map(objStr => {
  objStr = objStr.replace(/'/g, '"')
  return JSON.parse(objStr)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed I tried splitting it but doesnt seem to be an elegant solution